# How to order terms in polynomial expression (sympy, python) according to increasing degree (univariate case)?

Tags: python, printing, sympy, polynomials

In `sympy` (python) it seems that, by default, terms in univarate polynomials are ordered according to **decreasing** degrees: highest degree first, then second to highest, and so on. So, for example, a polynomial like

*x* + 1 + *x*^3 + 3*x*^6

will be printed out as 3*x*^6 + *x*^3 + *x* + 1.

I would like to **reverse** this order of polynomial terms in `sympy` to be **increasing** in the degrees. For the same example, the print-out should read 1 + *x* + *x*^3 + 3*x*^6. A solution that globally changes some parameter in program preamble is preferred but other options are also welcome.

---

Here is an MWE to play around with. It is different from the actual program I am working with. One part of the actual program (not the MWE) is printing out a list of recursively defined polynomials, e.g., P_n(x) = P_(n-1)(x) + a_n * x^n. It is easier for me to compare them when they are ordered by increasing degree. This is the motivation to change the order; doing it globally would probably just keep the code more readable (aesthetically pleasing). But the MWE is just for the same simple polynomial given in example above.

```py
import sympy as sym
from sympy import *

x = sym.Symbol('x')
polynomial = x + 1 + x**3 + 3*x**6
print(polynomial)
```

Output of MWE:

> `>>> 3*x**6 + x**3 + x + 1`

Desired output for MWE:

> `>>> 1 + x + x**3 + 3*x**6`

Comment: The are some options for `init_printing` that might help

Answer (score 1):

You can get the leading term using sympy.polys.polytools.LT:

LT(3*x ** 6 + x ** 3 + x + 1) == 3*x**6

So at least you can churn out terms recursively and print it in your own way.

Unfortunately I’ve been trying to find some way to print the terms in some fix order for a long while and find no solution better than this

Answer (score 0):

It's seems that there isn't an explicit way to do that and I found this approach to the problem:
to modify the print-representation of the object you can subclass its type and override the corresponding printing method (for LaTeX, MathML, ...) see [documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/printing.html?highlight=printer#example-of-custom-printing-method).

In this case [`_sympystr`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/printing.html?highlight=printer#module-sympy.printing.str) is used to "*generates readable representations of SymPy expressions.*"

Here a basic implementation:

```
from sympy import Poly, symbols, latex


class UPoly(Poly):
    """Modified univariative polynomial"""
  
    def _sympystr(self, printer) -> str:
        """increasing order of powers"""
        if self.is_multivariate:    # or: not self.is_univariate
            raise Exception('Error, Polynomial is not univariative')
        x = next(iter(expr.free_symbols))
        
        poly_print = ""
        for deg, coef in sorted(self.terms()):
            term = coef * x**deg[0]
            if coef.is_negative:
                term = -term     # fix sign
                poly_print += " - "
            else:
                poly_print += " + "
            poly_print += printer._print(term)
      
        return poly_print.lstrip(" +")

    def _latex(self, printer):
        return self._sympystr(printer)    # keep the order


x = symbols('x')
expr = 2*x + 6  - x**5
up = UPoly(expr)
print(up)
#6 + 2*x - x**5
print(latex(up))
#6 + 2 x - x^{5}
```